# What's the standard folder structure of a React+Redux project?

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the standard folder structure of a React+Redux project?

Where do you put the

- action types
- components
- etc...

When I look at [react-redux-socketio-chat](https://github.com/raineroviir/react-redux-socketio-chat/tree/master/src) I feel like this is maybe too much. Is it standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure suggested by Eni Arinde is aligned with what is suggested in the Redux documentation.

You may find this proposal interesting too:
https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Basically you make modules by bundling your action creators and reducers together. That does make a lot of sense as you will find that they are coupled together quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for how you structure you react+redux app, but there is a common pattern. This simple boilerplate [simple-redux-boilerplate](https://github.com/tsaiDavid/simple-redux-boilerplate) is a good example of the pattern commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

I have a boilerplate with basic setup of react redux following duck style. You can find it here: https://github.com/nlt2390/le-react-redux-duck

In general, this is how the folder structure looks like
[react redux file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW904.jpg)

- **components**: react components
- **containers**:  where components are connected to redux using `connect(Component)`
- **pages**: contains many *"components"* and *"containers"*
- **layouts**: contains *"pages"* & *"routes"* in `react-router` with some html wrapped outside them.
- **utils**: contains any functions, constants being used across the app, e.g `convertStringToNumber()`, `apiUrl`, etc
- **state**: contains *"actions"*, *"reducers"*, data in redux store, like `{ post: [], postDetails: {title: 'lorem' } }`